# CSS of GWT material design is not loading when that class is called by function of another class

Tags: css, gwt, material-design, materialize

I used GWT material design tabs for a process. It is working properly when used individually. Class Name- LiveClass

```
<m:MaterialRow>
  <m:MaterialColumn grid="s12">
    <m:MaterialTab backgroundColor="white">
      <m:MaterialTabItem grid="s6" waves="TEAL">
        <m:MaterialLink text="Upcoming Classes" href="upcoming" styleName="text-585858 bold capitalize"></m:MaterialLink>
      </m:MaterialTabItem>
      <m:MaterialTabItem waves="TEAL" grid="s6">
        <m:MaterialLink text="Completed Classes" href="completed" styleName="text-585858 bold capitalize"></m:MaterialLink>
      </m:MaterialTabItem>
    </m:MaterialTab>
  </m:MaterialColumn>
  <m:MaterialColumn m:id="upcoming" grid="s12">
    <m:MaterialLabel></m:MaterialLabel>
  </m:MaterialColumn>
  <m:MaterialColumn m:id="completed" grid="s12">
    <m:MaterialLabel></m:MaterialLabel>
  </m:MaterialColumn>
</m:MaterialRow>
```

But when I am using that class after making an object in a function of another class, only half of CSS classes are loaded and half are vanished.
Class Name- PageDesign and function- displayLiveClasses

```
private void displayLiveClasses() {
    postPanelBase.clear();
    postPanelBase.getPostPanel().add(new LiveClass());
}
```

Now in above class materialrow, tabs and other classes are not loading but working properly when "LiveClass" class is used individually.